# How to make the smooth scroll script not scroll till the top but a few pixels below

Tags: scroll, pixel, distance

I have the below jquery scrip on my website which works fine. I wanted to make the menu fixed on top, due to which now a part of the text gets hidden behind the fixed menu. how can i make the smooth scroll script to stop at 160px; from the .top of the browser

Thanks for any help in advance.
Cheers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

});
</script>
```

EDIT 2: I tried to play around with the script and i added a scrolloffset and a preventdefault() condition. It works when i click a link the first time a page is loaded. If i click on any other link again, it doesnt scroll at all.

```
var scrollOffset = 160;

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - scrollOffset;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          if(event != 'undefined') {
          event.preventDefault();}
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
            location.hash = target;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works but try to just add "+ 160" to the scroll-target.

Comment: I tried to replace "var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;" with "var targetOffset = $target.offset().top + 160;" But when it scrolls to the point where it gets hidden and stops, it jumps 50px or so down. Confused.

Comment: Still not sure if it works but try this ".animate({scrollTop: targetOffset + 160}, 1000,..."

Comment: This doesnt work either. I edited the code to get to the scroll point .. but now when i reload and click once it works, the second time when i click it doesnt .. untill i reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Remove `location.hash` since it scrolls back to the target element.